# SwiftUI .minimumScaleFactor() shrinks text too soon

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I use .minimumScaleFactor() in this simple example and it is not behaving as expected. Can someone explain why the text is scaled so small although having enough room to make it larger?

[image]

```
@available(iOS 14.0, *)
struct SwiftUIDynamicFontTest: View {
    var body: some View {
  
        VStack {
            Text("MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMZ")
                .minimumScaleFactor(0.5)
                .background(Color.green)
            Text("MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMZ")
                .minimumScaleFactor(0.5)
                .background(Color.green)
            Text("MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMZ")
                .minimumScaleFactor(0.5)
                .background(Color.green)
        }
        .frame(height: 390)
        .background(Color.blue)
    }
}

@available(iOS 14.0, *)
struct SwiftUIDynamicFontTest_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        SwiftUIDynamicFontTest()
    }
}
```

Comment: It scales the whole string and not line by line

Comment: But why in this tiny font size? Bigger font size would also fit for the first text block.

Comment: remove `.frame(height: 390)` and it'll be dynamic height!

Comment: That’s not what I want. I need the frame.

Comment: `.fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)` on the `VStack` could solve your problem.

Comment: That will prevent the down scaling completely.